# IOS Custom Segue and ContainerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have three buttons and a `UIView` (I call it `containerView`), tap each of the buttons, the `containerView` will show a View in a `UIViewController` through a custom segue, the buttons use one `IBAction` method(`switchView`), I put the three buttons in a `IBOutletCollection` called `navButtons`;
and in `viewDidLoad` I call `switchView` to make the `containerView` show first view controller.

And the code run well, no error,the only question is when I tap first button,the first `UIViewController` will shown in `containerView`, the UIImageView (buttons,labels,etc) should be in the centre  of the screen, but it never behave like this when it's first loaded, when I tap another button then tap first button again,it behaved as expected,
I have no idea what happened and what's the difference between first load and tapping it again.
IS THERE ANYTHING I MISSED IN THE CODE ?

I am not good at English,Sorry for anything unclear .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.availableIdentifier = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Seg1",@"Seg2",@"Seg3", nil];


    [self switchView:self.navButtons[0]];
}

- (IBAction)switchView:(UIButton *)sender
{

    [self setSelectedIndexs:(int)sender.tag];

}

- (void)setSelectedIndexs:(int)index
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:self.availableIdentifier[index] sender:self.navButtons[index]];

}

//Code of Custom Segue:
-(void)perform
{
    ViewController *controller = (ViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destController = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;
    for (UIView *view in controller.containerView.subviews)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    controller.currentController = destController;
    [controller.containerView addSubview:destController.view];

    [controller.containerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];


    [destController didMoveToParentViewController:controller];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add:

```
destController.view.frame = controller.containerView.frame;
```

before
 controller.currentController = destController;

Comment: Yes, This is the point and need to do a little more: set destController.view.frame's y to 0; Thanks for the answer;

Answer (score 0):

is  your clipSubViews set in UIViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thanks for the answer of Bojan Bozovic ;

```
CGRect frame = controller.containerView.frame;
frame.origin.y = 0;
destController.view.frame = frame;
```

Add above before controller.currentController = destController;